# E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: openstack, python3

I have been trying to install Devstack and this happened while  "./stack.sh".

Comment: 1. nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list
2. put under comment this line : 
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial main

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should remove this PPA from the system with

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
```

and then run

```
sudo apt update
```

to get actual package indexes.

Please note if you really need the packages from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6), then consider to [contact JonathonF](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+contactuser) and ask him about packaging for *disco*. See example text in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110996/66509).

Comment: That command is to add a repository not remove it. you need to add --remove

Comment: Removed it, but doing a `sudo apt update` still results in error: "InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.5/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is no longer signed.
".

Comment: @david you have to visit the https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf to understand that *PPAs which have moved to become private access* including *Python 3.5*.

Comment: @N0rbert thx, I already saw some similar statement. But how to solve it? I simply want to write some OSS project :-) ...and I don't need this PPA, i guess, i just want to get rid of it.