# How to fix "The repository ... does not have a Release file" on Ubuntu 16.04.6?

Tags: apt

On Ubuntu 16.04.6 I am trying to run the command

```
sudo apt update
```

but I get the following error:

```
...
Hit:27 https://dl.bintray.com/getinsomnia/Insomnia  Release
Hit:31 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I get the same error when I remove files like

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

as suggested in one other similar question [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996718/ubuntu-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file).

What else can I try?

Content of file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
deb https://dl.bintray.com/gauge/gauge-deb stable main
```

Comment: The PPAs are now PRIVATE access only, see https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Any useful suggestion that helps me fix this problem?

Comment: Found the solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135822/e-the-repository-http-ppa-launchpad-net-jonathonf-python-3-6-ubuntu-disco-re